# Remove list in lists that satisfied the condition

Tags: python, ocr, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a quick OCR for specific use, I know should've just write a preprocessor for normal OCR and that would been faster but this idea came up to me first and I figure I should just try it anyway haha. This program would take a picture on a region of screen and identify the number within it, as of right now, it's only 0 and 1 but I've been working on it and stuck with some problems. Here is my code

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('`'):
        Firstlist =  list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(image[0], confidence = 0.95,region=( 1570 , 990 , 230 , 70 )))
        print(len(Firstlist))
        Firstlist1 = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(image1, confidence = 0.95,region=( 1570 , 990 , 230 , 70 ))) + Firstlist
        print(len(Firstlist1))
        print(Firstlist) 
        if len(Firstlist) > 0:
            print(Firstlist[0][0])
            #compare all first instance of that number and eliminate all duplicated with in a different of 5 x pixel
        break
```

Which would identify some predetermined set of number like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mwi4.png) on screen and right now, it would give me a set of coordinate for number zero on screen, here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H2Gk.png), please ignore other parts, it's just me playing around. Problem with this is `pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen` would sometimes generate duplicate value of the same picture within the coordinate ranging from approx 0-5 pixels if not set the confidence level right.

Example:

Value supposed to be `[ (1655,1024,20,26),(1675,1024,20,26) ]` but will yield a third value like `[ (1655,1024,20,26), (1658,1024,20,26), (1675,1024,20,26) ]`.

And that's why I'm trying to make a correction for this. Is there anyway to identified if that x value of second duplicate coordinate is within a range of 0-5 pixels to the first coordinate and just delete it, moving the rest up the ladder so that the number would come up right and in order? Thank you!

Note: I'm still working on learning the list removal process by myself, and read the removing list with lambda to me is like gibberish. Please forgive me if something is wrong. Have a good day y'all!

Comment: How about just getting the min and max values among the first elements?

Comment: Hi @ThuYaKyaw, I'm not quite get your idea, can you please explain it? Because the trash value usually happen in large amount and not guarantee to one or two so I think I'd have to eliminate them that way. But if you have any idea that would work I'd be happy to hear about it!

Comment: Sure. It appears that you only want 2 coordinates out of N coordinates. In your example [ (1655,1024,20,26), (1658,1024,20,26), (1675,1024,20,26) ], instead of looping through the entire list you could try min(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0]) and max(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0]). That would gives you the output [ (1655,1024,20,26),(1675,1024,20,26) ]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I actually want the max coordinate possible without duplicate though. That said, if the number in the picture above is 1000, it would give off one 1 and 3 zeros. Hence I'd get 4 coordinates eventually, that was just an example up there. Anyway, I appreciate your response, alex got it right though so I've got what I need. Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
if len(Firstlist) > 2:
    elems = [f[0] for f in Firstlist]  # create a list of just first index
    i = 0
    while i < len(elems) - 1:  # iterate through the list with i
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(elems):  # iterate through the rest of the list with j
            if abs(elems[i] - elems[j]) <= 5:  # if item at index i is within 5 pixels of item at index j
                del elems[j]   # delete item j and continue
            else:
                j += 1    # otherwise move to next item
        i += 1  #  Move to next i item
```

Comment: Hi alex, the logic workout successfully but, I've encountered this problem while fixing the code. Tried to search google to understand it but no luck. I think it  cannot read the j list because this is empty "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" cause it seem to happened on the "del Firstlist[j] line, just the last line of the code

Comment: @VuongDuong  sorry I forgot to add the break at the end... try it with that.

Comment: @VuongDuong  I actually rewrote it to use while loops that way if your list ever grows beyond the length of 2, it will make the comparison on each element.  plus it shouldn't cause an index error this way.

Comment: Oh, I'm just being dumb lol. This worked out perfect as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: and much appreciated for the code edited also. I planned on doing that on myself but you got that down too, will check that back later and add it if possible. Please have a good day as you just made my day better!

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [ (1655,1024,20,26), (1658,1024,20,26), (1675,1024,20,26) ]
x = [list1[0]] + [x for x in list1 if abs(list1[0][0] - x[0]) > 5]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[(1655, 1024, 20, 26), (1675, 1024, 20, 26)]
```

Comment: I like your solution too @Bert2me!

Comment: Hi Bert, love your solution, just that I got what I need right now but your solution is extremely short and easy to understand. Thank you!